# InvokeRequired keeps returning false when true is expected

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, invokerequired

I have the following test code. It does nothing useful, but it's there for me to understand VB:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Sandbox
    Public Shared num As NumericUpDown

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim objWrk As Worker
        objWrk = New Worker
        objWrk.Show()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Worker
    Public Sub Show()
        Dim runThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Run)      ' Call the runner in a seperate thread
        runThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Run()
        runToggle(1000)
    End Sub

    Public Delegate Sub runToggleInvoker(ByVal value As Integer)
    Public Sub runToggle(ByVal value As Integer)
        If Sandbox.Label1.InvokeRequired = True Then
            Sandbox.Label1.Invoke(New runToggleInvoker(AddressOf runToggle), value)
        Else
            Sandbox.Label1.Text = value
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The form consists of a `Button` and a `Label`.

Just for learning purposes I've put the method to change the text in the label in another thread. However the `InvokeRequired` value keeps returning `False`. How is this possible? The `Label1`is created in the main thread, and it is being adjusted in the runThread hence `InvokeRequired` should give True.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013954/invokerequired-of-form-false-and-invokerequired-of-contained-control-true) I read that this happens when the handle for the form is not created yet so I changed my `Run` method:

```
Public Sub Run()
            Sandbox.Show()
            runToggle(1000)
        End Sub
```

This does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Control.InvokeRequired Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx)

If the control's handle does not yet exist, InvokeRequired searches up the control's parent chain until it finds a control or form that does have a window handle. If no appropriate handle can be found, the InvokeRequired method returns **false**.

Comment: OK, but I tried to create that handle first coding `Sandbox.Show()`. This should create a handle, right?

Comment: You are now calling Show from inside the worker thread, so the invoke will not be required. Show the form from the main thread instead.